# Woocomerce. How to exclude (hide) products from catalog and search result?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

We have function like that:

```
must_be_hide($post_id) {
  $bool = in_array($post_id, array(1, 2, 3, 4 ,5));
  return $bool;
}
```

How with this function hide product from woocomerce catalog (shop) and search result?

Answer (score 0):

You have to alter the search loop and use the following code:

```
$_pf = new WC_Product_Factory();
$_product = $_pf->get_product($id); // assuming $id is available as the code is inside the loop
$_product->is_visible()
```